# Store function is not passing field value

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

The following function

```
 public function storeTally()
    {
        

        $tally_meal = request()->validate([
                'date_served' => ['required'],
                'meal_type_id' => ['required', Rule::exists('meal_types', 'id')],
                'tally' => ['required'],
         ]);

        $tally_meal['site_id'] = auth()->user()->site->id;
        $tally_meal['user_id'] = auth()->id();
        $tally_meal['sfa_id'] = auth()->user()->sfa->id;
        
        StudentMeal::create($tally_meal);    

        return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Meal added.');
    }
}
```

returns this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'sfa_id' doesn't have a default value

insert into `student_meals` (`date_served`, `meal_type_id`, `tally`, `site_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2022-05-30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2022-05-31 01:50:07, 2022-05-31 01:50:07)
```

I've tried passing just an integer and get the same error. I can't figure out why it's not recognizing the sfa_id field.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should check `$fillable` in model  (`StudentMeal`). field `sfa_id` is not null and does not have a default value .
In your model (`StudentMeal`)  of you may be `$fillable` does not contain field `sfa_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your Model    StudentMeal
Check if    sfa_id is there in the    $fillable variable.
If it is not available, then add that field.